# Troubleshooting Bootstrap button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Submit Button is not working if I put it on a different container or row

If my code is formatted like this the submit button works

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <form>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
       </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

If my code is formatted like this the submit button do not work

```
 <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
       <form>

           {{ some other codes }}

    </div>

    <div class="row">

          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
       </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I dont get any error message.. the button is there but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your div's are not closing properly. Your form starts in a div and ends in a different div. I'm not sure what you wanted to do, but you need to make sure the `form` tags both begin and end inside the same div.

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
       <form>

           {{ some other codes }}

         <div class="row">
           <button type="submit">Submit</button>

         </div>
       </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you order your tags like below so they close properly. Then your button will work.
Take a look at [HTML basics Nesting elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/HTML_basics#Nesting_elements) from MDN.

```
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      {{ some other codes }}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button id="js" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```